# How to do effective logging in Spark application

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark application code written in Scala that runs a series of Spark-SQL statements. These results are calculated by calling an action 'Count' in the end against the final dataframe. I would like to know what is the best way to do logging from within a Spark-scala application job? Since all the dataframes (around 20) in number are computed using a single action in the end, what are my options when it comes to logging the outputs/sequence/success of some statements.

Question is little generic in nature. Since spark works on lazy evaluation, the execeution plan is decided by spark and I want to know till what point application statements ran successfully and what were the intermediate results at that stage.

The intention here being to monitor the long running task and see till which point it was fine and where the the problems creeped in.

If we try to put logging before/after transformations then it gets printed when code is read. So, the logging has to be done with custom messages during the actual execution (calling the action in the end of the scala code). If I try to put count/take/first etc in between the code then the execution of job slows down a lot.

Comment: Why not to use spark UI? It will provide you with real-time information about your spark application and logs from each executor. (https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-webui.html)

Answer (score 2):

I understand the problem that you are facing. Let me put out a simple solution for this.

You need to make use of `org.apache.log4j.Logger`. Use following lines of code to generate logger messages.

```
org.apache.log4j.Logger logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getRootLogger();

logger.error(errorMessage);
logger.info(infoMessage);
logger.debug(debugMessage);
```

Now, in order to redirect these messages to a log file, you need to create a log4j property file with below contents.

```
# Root logger option

# Set everything to be logged to the console
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n

# Settings to quiet third party logs that are too verbose
log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty=OFF
log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle=OFF
log4j.logger.org.spark-project.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler=OFF
log4j.logger.org.spark-project.jetty.server=OFF
log4j.logger.org.spark-project.jetty=OFF
log4j.category.org.spark_project.jetty=OFF
log4j.logger.Remoting=OFF
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$exprTyper=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.parquet=ERROR
log4j.logger.parquet=ERROR

# Setting properties to have logger logs in local file system 
log4j.appender.rolling=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rolling.encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.rolling.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rolling.layout.conversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n
log4j.appender.rolling.maxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.rolling.maxFileSize=50MB
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark=OFF
log4j.logger.org.spark-project=OFF
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop=OFF
log4j.logger.io.netty=OFF
log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=OFF
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, rolling
log4j.appender.rolling.file=/tmp/logs/application.log
```

You can name the log file in the last statement. Ensure the folders at every node with appropriate permissions.

Now, we need to pass the configurations while submitting the spark job as follows.

```
 --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=spark-log4j.properties --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=spark-log4j.properties
```

And,

```
--files "location of spark-log4j.properties file"
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can use log4j lib from maven

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
<version>${log4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

For logging, first you need to create a logger object and then you can do logging at different log levels like info, error, warning. Below is the example of logging info in spark scala using log4j:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager
val logger = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass.getName)

logger.info("logging message")
```

So, to add info at some points you can use logger.info("logging message") at that point.